# ViewPager2 - Fragment change in PIP mode

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x, android-viewpager2

I have to develop an app that has a list of videos and also support PIP mode. I have used ViewPager2 with vertical orientation and ExoPlayer. FragmentStateAdapter is use for ViewPager2 adapter

**Problems.**

1. When screens enter PIP mode fragment automatically change. ViewPager's **onPageSelected** function and video changed.
2. When screen comes in fullscreen from PIP then multiple videos plays simultaneously. Its like multiple players are working.
3. Next fragment also shown in screen after opening keyboard.

**Code -**

1. Manifest

**2. HomeActivity**

```
override fun onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint()       
    if (fragment != null && isPIPSupport() && !isInPictureInPictureMode) {
        enterPIPMode()
    }
}

fun enterPIPMode() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N
        && packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE)
    ) {
        val aspectRatio = Rational(
            3, 4
        )
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val params =
                PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
                    .setAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
                    .build()

            enterPictureInPictureMode(params)
        } else {
            enterPictureInPictureMode()
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Adapter**

```
 class ViewPagerStateAdapter(
private val productList: ArrayList<Product>,
private val fragmentActivity: Fragment, val frgManager: FragmentManager
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return productList.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
  
        return VideoDetailFragment.newInstance(position)
}
}
```

**4. Fragment**

```
class VideoDetailFragment : BaseFragment() , GestureListener {
private var position:Int=0
private lateinit var mExoPlayerManager: ExoPlayerManager
private lateinit var mDetector: GestureDetectorCompat
private lateinit var mHomeActivity: HomeActivity
companion object {
    fun newInstance(position: Int): Fragment {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("position", position)
        val frg = VideoDetailFragment()
        frg.arguments = bundle
        return frg
    }
}

override fun getToolbarId(): Int {
    return -1
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mHomeActivity=activity as HomeActivity
   position= arguments?.getInt("position")?:0
    mExoPlayerManager = ExoPlayerManager(requireContext())
    initializeGestureDetector()
}
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_detail, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    manageExoPlayer(view)
}

private fun manageExoPlayer(view:View)
{
    val exoPlayerView = view.findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.exo_player_clp)
    managePlayer(exoPlayerView,position,SLPList.productList[position])
}
fun managePlayer(exoPlayerView: PlayerView, position: Int, product: Product) {

    product.getVideoUrl()?.let {
        mExoPlayerManager.setPlayerView(exoPlayerView)
        exoPlayerView.player = mExoPlayerManager.getPlayer()
        Log.v("LiveVideoActivity", mExoPlayerManager.getCurrentTime().toString())
        val mergingMediaSource = mExoPlayerManager.getMediaSource(it)
        mExoPlayerManager.prepare(mergingMediaSource, true, true)
        mExoPlayerManager.setPlayWhenReady(false)

    }
}
override fun onDestroyView() {
    mExoPlayerManager.releasePlayer()
    super.onDestroyView()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
if (!mHomeActivity.isInPIP()) {
    mExoPlayerManager.onPause()
}

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (!mHomeActivity.isInPIP()) {
        mExoPlayerManager.onResume()
    }

}
private fun initializeGestureDetector() {
    val customGesture = CustomGestureDetector(this)
    mDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(requireContext(), customGesture)
}

}
```

**6. Set up Adapter**

```
  private fun setupViewPager() {
    liveShowAdapter = ViewPagerStateAdapter(SLPList.productList, this, childFragmentManager)
    mLiveShowViewPager?.apply {
        adapter = liveShowAdapter
        offscreenPageLimit =
            3
        registerOnPageChangeCallback(registerChangeCallBack)

    }
    }
```